# Conditionals in Low Seach examples giving php errors

Tags: low-search

I'm having two PHP Errors while testing a basic Low Search example. The code can be found [here](http://pastie.org/10710807).

The errors shows **only while logged in** (afaik as super-admin). I'm using EE 2.8.1. Results are working fine.

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: User Warning
>
> Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if low_search_category ~ '/\b'.category_id.'\b/'}
>
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php
>
> Line Number: 2640
>
> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/colegios/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 442

Found [this](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20437/php-errors-for-custom-field-conditionals-where-the-data-contains-quotation-) at EE bug; but I don't know how to solve it? Should I upgrade to a newer EE2 version? 2.8.1 is stable for me and I want to avoid problems with others addons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the top of [the example page in the Low Search docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples):

> **Note**: these examples feature conditionals using the [Matches Operator](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#matches-operator) introduced in EE 2.9.0. If you’re using an older version of ExpressionEngine, you can use the [IN conditionals](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#in-conditionals) instead.

So, either use the [IN conditionals](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#in-conditionals) and continue using EE 2.8.1, or upgrade EE to v2.10.3, which is the latest v2 version at the moment.

Comment: I will check my others addons to see if they are compatible with latest EE2 version to update. In the meanwhile, tried the IN conditionals and they are working as a charm. Thank you low!